# Deleting multiple items from Gridview WinRT issue

Tags: gridview, windows-runtime

I'm working on a WinRT app where on a page, I have a GridView displaying multiple items (some notes, similar to the gridview by creating an ItemsPage template) with a source set through binding to a table in a database containing those notes. The Grid's `SelectionMode`  is set to `Extended`. On this same page, in the app bar I've got a delete button. When I select multiple items from the GridView and I press the delete button I want them all to be deleted. The problem is they don't get all deleted, just half of them and this is very strange (or maybe not, I don't really know what I'm missing here)

Here's how the delete button's code looks like :

```
foreach (var item in ViewNotesGridView.SelectedItems)
{
    App.ViewModel.RemoveNote((Note)item);
}
```

And here are some of the GridView's settings :

```
<GridView 
    x:Name="ViewNotesGridView" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Notes}"
    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource Standard200X200NoteTemplate}"
    SelectionMode="Extended"
    IsItemClickEnabled="True"
>
```

If I try to delete them one by one, it works, but if I try to delete multiple items at the same time, it will never delete all of those that were selected.

For example I had notes 1, 2, 3, ... 10. I select them all and click delete and after this I still remain with notes 2, 4, 6, 8, 10...

Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Can you also post the code found in the RemoveNote() method of your ViewModel class.

Comment: @SandraWalters I'm using a dll, WinRTDatabase, RemoveNote method actually calls a Remove method on a Collectionof type Note, my model. I did today some research and some tries and I found out two ways of solving this, either by using something like :while (ViewNotesGridView.SelectedItems.Count != 0) {...} or a second way : foreach (var item in ViewNotesGridView.SelectedItems.ToList()) {...}